# Laravel Tinker Error: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError : Call to undefined method Psy\Configuration::getLoop()

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, tinker

I am trying to run `php artisan tinker` on my project and get this error:

```php
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method Psy\Configuration::getLoop()

  at /var/www/[my_project]/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php:80
    76|     public function __construct(Configuration $config = null)
    77|     {
    78|         $this->config   = $config ?: new Configuration();
    79|         $this->cleaner  = $this->config->getCodeCleaner();
  > 80|         $this->loop     = $this->config->getLoop();
    81|         $this->context  = new Context();
    82|         $this->includes = array();
    83|         $this->readline = $this->config->getReadline();
    84|         $this->inputBuffer = array();
```

As you see the problem is on line **80**.
I think I must mention that I once used `Throwable` and `FatalThrowableError` in one of my controllers to get the `Exception` because the general `Exception` could not get the `Exception` I was getting! I handled that throwable error another way and was able to get that `Exception` by `Exception` itself! Anyway, I have not used `Throwable` or `FatalThrowableError` anywhere in my code anymore, but I still get the aforementioned error.

How can I get `php artisan tinker` work again? I think the problem is somehow related to the `composer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just deleted my `vendor` folder manually, and tried running `composer install`. By doing this, the `php artisan tinker` command worked properly again.
This might not be the right solution, but anyway, it works again. Maybe just deleting `vendor/psy` folder and running `composer install` would do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer doesn't solve the problem, check if

`bootstrap/cache/config.php` exists.

If it exists, try deleting the file. It should solve the problem.